# How to convert the relations in ann files to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple ann files with contents like this.

```
T1  MajorClaim 1 162    A combination of mitoxantrone plus prednisone is preferable to prednisone alone for reduction of pain in men with metastatic, hormone-resistant, prostate cancer.
T2  Premise 992 1058    At 6 weeks, both groups showed improvement in several HQL domains,
T3  Premise 1063 1187   only physical functioning and pain were better in the mitoxantrone-plus-prednisone group than in the prednisone-alone group.
T4  Premise 1188 1447   After 6 weeks, patients taking prednisone showed no improvement in HQL scores, whereas those taking mitoxantrone plus prednisone showed significant improvements in global quality of life (P =.009), four functioning domains, and nine symptoms (.001 < P <. 01),
T6  Premise 1452 1568   the improvement (> 10 units on a scale of 0 to100) lasted longer than in the prednisone-alone group (.004 < P <.05).
T7  Premise 1569 1768   The addition of mitoxantrone to prednisone after failure of prednisone alone was associated with improvements in pain, pain impact, pain relief, insomnia, and global quality of life (.001 < P <.003).
T8  Claim 1769 1945 Treatment with mitoxantrone plus prednisone was associated with greater and longer-lasting improvement in several HQL domains and symptoms than treatment with prednisone alone.
R1  Support Arg1:T8 Arg2:T1 
R2  Support Arg1:T2 Arg2:T8 
R3  Support Arg1:T3 Arg2:T8 
R4  Support Arg1:T6 Arg2:T8 
R5  Support Arg1:T4 Arg2:T8 
R6  Support Arg1:T7 Arg2:T1
```

I want to convert the rows having relations to pandas dataframe in the form of something like this.

| Relation | sentence1 | sentence2 | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | Treatment with mitoxantrone plus prednisone was associated with greater and longer-lasting improvement in several HQL domains and symptoms than treatment with prednisone alone. | A combination of mitoxantrone plus prednisone is preferable to prednisone alone for reduction of pain in men with metastatic, hormone-resistant, prostate cancer. | Support |
| R2 | At 6 weeks, both groups showed improvement in several HQL domains, | Treatment with mitoxantrone plus prednisone was associated with greater and longer-lasting improvement in several HQL domains and symptoms than treatment with prednisone alone. | Support |

The dataframe should include all the relations from R1 to R6. How do I proceed?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want the output to be? When you say "where T8 and T1 should be the text corresponding to it" can you edit your question to show what that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more direct method, but the approach below has the following steps. (1) Separate the R and T rows into separate dfs. (2) Create a dictionary mapping {'T1':'A combination...','T2':'At 6 weeks..'} etc. (3) From the R_df, extract the T labels into a new out_df. (4) Use the dictionary to map T label to sentence and create a new column in the out_df. (5) Reshape the out_df to be in the format you want.

I didn't include the `Label` column in your output, I felt the main goal of your question was how to map from T-label to T-sentence

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': [
        'T1','T2','T3','T4','T6','T7','T8',
        'R1','R2','R3','R4','R5','R6',
    ],
    'description': [
        'MajorClaim 1 162','Premise 992 1058','Premise 1063 1187','Premise 1188 1447',
        'Premise 1452 1568','Premise 1569 1768','Claim 1769 1945',
        'Support Arg1:T8 Arg2:T1','Support Arg1:T2 Arg2:T8','Support Arg1:T3 Arg2:T8',
        'Support Arg1:T6 Arg2:T8','Support Arg1:T4 Arg2:T8','Support Arg1:T7 Arg2:T1',
    ],
    'sentence': [
        'A combination of mitoxantrone plus prednisone is preferable to prednisone alone for reduction of pain in men with metastatic, hormone-resistant, prostate cancer.',
        'At 6 weeks, both groups showed improvement in several HQL domains,',
        'only physical functioning and pain were better in the mitoxantrone-plus-prednisone group than in the prednisone-alone group.',
        'After 6 weeks, patients taking prednisone showed no improvement in HQL scores, whereas those taking mitoxantrone plus prednisone showed significant improvements in global quality of life (P =.009), four functioning domains, and nine symptoms (.001 < P <. 01),',
        'the improvement (> 10 units on a scale of 0 to100) lasted longer than in the prednisone-alone group (.004 < P <.05).',
        'The addition of mitoxantrone to prednisone after failure of prednisone alone was associated with improvements in pain, pain impact, pain relief, insomnia, and global quality of life (.001 < P <.003).',
        'Treatment with mitoxantrone plus prednisone was associated with greater and longer-lasting improvement in several HQL domains and symptoms than treatment with prednisone alone.',
        '','','','','','',
    ]
})

#Separate the T and R rows into different tables
T_df = df[df['label'].str.startswith('T')]
R_df = df[df['label'].str.startswith('R')]

#Create a dictionary of {'T1':'A combination...','T2':'At 6 weeks..'} etc
t_label_to_sentence = dict(zip(T_df['label'],T_df['sentence']))

#Search for T followed by a number in the description of the R_df
#create a new column called T_label with the hits
out_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label':R_df['label'],
    'T_label':R_df['description'].str.findall(':(T[0-9]+)'),
}).explode('T_label')

#Map the T sentences onto the out_df
out_df['sentence'] = out_df['T_label'].map(t_label_to_sentence)

#Pivot the table to wide-form (need to add a new column to help with the pivot)
out_df['sentence_number'] = 'sentence_'+out_df.groupby('label').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

out_df = out_df.pivot(
    index = 'label',
    columns = 'sentence_number',
    values = 'sentence',
)


out_df
```